# "this" vs. "element" keyword in X++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

When writing code in X++ you sometimes need to reference `this.functionYouWant()` and sometimes it is `element.FunctionYouWant()`. Sometimes both are in scope. I often try one and if the function I want isn't there I try the other. Is there a rule that explains when to use `this` and when to use `element`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`this` can be used in any objects to reference the current object and member methods.

MorphX forms and reports are composite objects.

In forms the collection of objects is contained within a `FormRun` object. You can reference members in the outer `FormRun` object by using the `element` reference.

If your code is placed at the top level there are no functional difference between `this` and `element`.

If your code is placed in a FormDataSource `this` will reference the datasource but `element` will reference the `FormRun`.

Answer (score 0):

"This" can be used only refers to the same class objects but "element" is access the form methods into any form level(like datasouce level,design level)if the functionality of method is same we can use