# How refresh a grid of another form on Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Does anyone know how to refresh a grid on another form through a button? I mean when I add something, I want to see it reflected immediately on the other form.

[image]

Comment: Is the form your are updating get opened from the other form? In that case you can capture the caller as Formrun caller = element.args().caller(); in init method. Then use caller.dataSource().research(true); on save button or modified method of fields to refresh caller.

Comment: Hello again, thanks you for your time :D, form A  have the grid, and when I press a button appers the form B whats its where I add data to the grid on the form A, so like I understand I put all on the form B `Formrun caller;` on the ClassDeclaration, `caller = element.args().caller();` on the Init method and `caller.dataSource().research(true);` on the add button, but sends me an error:: FormRun Object Not initialized...

Comment: When you open form B from form A add the following line of code to initialize caller `args.caller(this)`. Also you should always check that object is not null `if (element.args() != null && element.args().caller() != null`.

Comment: Is not working :s this is the code of the field with leave method `ret = super();
    
    args = new args();
    args.caller(this);
    args.parm( Field_OnFormA );
    args.name( formstr( Form_B ) );

    formRun = classFactory.formRunClass( Args );
    formRun.init();
    formrun.run();
    formrun.wait();

    return ret;`

Comment: This is the code on the ClassDeclaration form_B `public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
{
    Formrun caller;

}`

Comment: here is the code on the init : `super();  caller = element.args().caller();
    if(!element.args().caller())
    {
        throw error("Cant Run Directly");
    }
`

Comment: and here the button `super();

    caller.dataSource().research(true);`

Comment: If your code is placed on control then use `args.caller(element)` instead of `args.caller(this)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260403/this-vs-element-keyword-in-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the form your are updating get opened from the other form, Then in updating form class declaration declare caller as `Formrun caller;` Then in Init method initialize caller. `caller = element.args().caller();` Then on save button clicked method after super, call this `caller.dataSource().research(true)`;

Comment: Or `args.record().datasource().research(true)`.